# Theme Customizer not displaying saved values in wp_head (CSS)

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I've been learning hot to add theme customizer feature to a theme.
Used few sources for the code and help, but chose the Codex in the end.

I am using a snippet from the codex itself, slightly modified to add more settings.

The only thing I've done was to add few more color options. I am also using the Java script to show live changes.

THE ISSUE:
the function which calls back the settings saved values and adds the new values to a STYLE section in the header - Doesn't work. :/

it seems that it will not pull the saved value (or even the default one) with "get_theme_mod"

can someone have a look at the code and point me to the right direction please ??

Here's my functions.php file.

```
<?php

class UnReady_Customize {

   public static function register ( $wp_customize ) {
      //1. Define a new section (if desired) to the Theme Customizer
      $wp_customize->add_section( 'mytheme_options',
         array(
            'title' => __( 'MyTheme Options', 'mytheme' ), //Visible title of section
            'priority' => 35, //Determines what order this appears in
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Capability needed to tweak
            'description' => __('Allows you to customize some example settings for MyTheme.', 'mytheme'), //Descriptive tooltip
         )
      );

      //2. Register new settings to the WP database...
      $wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_options[body_background]', //Give it a SERIALIZED name (so all theme settings can live under one db record)
         array(
            'default' => '#FFFFFF', //Default setting/value to save
            'type' => 'option', //Is this an 'option' or a 'theme_mod'?
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Optional. Special permissions for accessing this setting.
            'transport' => 'postMessage', //What triggers a refresh of the setting? 'refresh' or 'postMessage' (instant)?
         )
      );

           $wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_options[site_title]', //Give it a SERIALIZED name (so all theme settings can live under one db record)
         array(
            'default' => '#000000', //Default setting/value to save
            'type' => 'option', //Is this an 'option' or a 'theme_mod'?
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Optional. Special permissions for accessing this setting.
            'transport' => 'postMessage', //What triggers a refresh of the setting? 'refresh' or 'postMessage' (instant)?
         )
      );

           $wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_options[site_description]', //Give it a SERIALIZED name (so all theme settings can live under one db record)
         array(
            'default' => '#000000', //Default setting/value to save
            'type' => 'option', //Is this an 'option' or a 'theme_mod'?
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Optional. Special permissions for accessing this setting.
            'transport' => 'postMessage', //What triggers a refresh of the setting? 'refresh' or 'postMessage' (instant)?
         )
      );


          $wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_options[link_textcolor]', //Give it a SERIALIZED name (so all theme settings can live under one db record)
         array(
            'default' => '#0076d1', //Default setting/value to save
            'type' => 'option', //Is this an 'option' or a 'theme_mod'?
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Optional. Special permissions for accessing this setting.
            'transport' => 'postMessage', //What triggers a refresh of the setting? 'refresh' or 'postMessage' (instant)?
         )
      );      

          $wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_options[link_hover_textcolor]', //Give it a SERIALIZED name (so all theme settings can live under one db record)
         array(
            'default' => '#0066d1', //Default setting/value to save
            'type' => 'option', //Is this an 'option' or a 'theme_mod'?
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Optional. Special permissions for accessing this setting.
            'transport' => 'postMessage', //What triggers a refresh of the setting? 'refresh' or 'postMessage' (instant)?
         )
      );

      //3. Finally, we define the control itself (which links a setting to a section and renders the HTML controls)...
      $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( //Instantiate the color control class
         $wp_customize, //Pass the $wp_customize object (required)
         'mytheme_bg_color', //Set a unique ID for the control
         array(
            'label' => __( 'Background Color', 'mytheme' ), //Admin-visible name of the control
            'section' => 'colors', //ID of the section this control should render in (can be one of yours, or a WordPress default section)
            'settings' => 'mytheme_options[body_background]', //Which setting to load and manipulate (serialized is okay)
            'priority' => 10, //Determines the order this control appears in for the specified section
         )
      ) );

      $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( //Instantiate the color control class
         $wp_customize, //Pass the $wp_customize object (required)
         'mytheme_site_title_color', //Set a unique ID for the control
         array(
            'label' => __( 'Site Title Color', 'mytheme' ), //Admin-visible name of the control
            'section' => 'colors', //ID of the section this control should render in (can be one of yours, or a WordPress default section)
            'settings' => 'mytheme_options[site_title]', //Which setting to load and manipulate (serialized is okay)
            'priority' => 11, //Determines the order this control appears in for the specified section
         )
      ) );

      $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( //Instantiate the color control class
         $wp_customize, //Pass the $wp_customize object (required)
         'mytheme_site_description_color', //Set a unique ID for the control
         array(
            'label' => __( 'Site Description Color', 'mytheme' ), //Admin-visible name of the control
            'section' => 'colors', //ID of the section this control should render in (can be one of yours, or a WordPress default section)
            'settings' => 'mytheme_options[site_description]', //Which setting to load and manipulate (serialized is okay)
            'priority' => 12, //Determines the order this control appears in for the specified section
         )
      ) );       
      $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( //Instantiate the color control class
         $wp_customize, //Pass the $wp_customize object (required)
         'mytheme_link_textcolor', //Set a unique ID for the control
         array(
            'label' => __( 'Link Color', 'mytheme' ), //Admin-visible name of the control
            'section' => 'colors', //ID of the section this control should render in (can be one of yours, or a WordPress default section)
            'settings' => 'mytheme_options[link_textcolor]', //Which setting to load and manipulate (serialized is okay)
            'priority' => 13, //Determines the order this control appears in for the specified section
         )
      ) );

      $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( //Instantiate the color control class
         $wp_customize, //Pass the $wp_customize object (required)
         'mytheme_link_hover_textcolor', //Set a unique ID for the control
         array(
            'label' => __( 'Link Hover Color', 'mytheme' ), //Admin-visible name of the control
            'section' => 'colors', //ID of the section this control should render in (can be one of yours, or a WordPress default section)
            'settings' => 'mytheme_options[link_hover_textcolor]', //Which setting to load and manipulate (serialized is okay)
            'priority' => 14, //Determines the order this control appears in for the specified section
         )
      ) );


   }

   /**
    * This will output the custom WordPress settings to the live theme's WP head.
    *
    * Used by hook: 'wp_head'
    *
    * @see add_action('wp_head',$func)
    * @since MyTheme 1.0
    */

   public static function header_output() {
      ?>
      <!--Customizer CSS-->
      <style type="text/css">

                         body { color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('mytheme_options[body_background]'); ?>; }
             .site-title { color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('mytheme_options[site_title]'); ?>; }
                         .site-description { color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('mytheme_options[site_description]'); ?>; }
                         #content a { color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('mytheme_options[link_textcolor]'); ?>; }
                         #content a:hover { color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('mytheme_options[link_hover_textcolor]'); ?>; }
      </style>
      <!--/Customizer CSS-->
      <?php
   }

   /**
    * This outputs the javascript needed to automate the live settings preview.
    * Also keep in mind that this function isn't necessary unless your settings
    * are using 'transport'=>'postMessage' instead of the default 'transport'
    * => 'refresh'
    *
    * Used by hook: 'customize_preview_init'
    *
    * @see add_action('customize_preview_init',$func)
    * @since MyTheme 1.0
    */
   public static function live_preview() {
      wp_enqueue_script(
           'mytheme-themecustomizer', // Give the script a unique ID
           get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-customizer.js', // Define the path to the JS file
           array(  'jquery', 'customize-preview' ), // Define dependencies
           '', // Define a version (optional)
           true // Specify whether to put in footer (leave this true)
      );
   }

    /**
     * This will generate a line of CSS for use in header output. If the setting
     * ($mod_name) has no defined value, the CSS will not be output.
     *
     * @uses get_theme_mod()
     * @param string $selector CSS selector
     * @param string $style The name of the CSS *property* to modify
     * @param string $mod_name The name of the 'theme_mod' option to fetch
     * @param string $prefix Optional. Anything that needs to be output before the CSS property
     * @param string $postfix Optional. Anything that needs to be output after the CSS property
     * @param bool $echo Optional. Whether to print directly to the page (default: true).
     * @return string Returns a single line of CSS with selectors and a property.
     * @since MyTheme 1.0
     */
    public static function generate_css( $selector, $style, $mod_name, $prefix='', $postfix='', $echo=true ) {
      $return = '';
      $mod = get_theme_mod($mod_name);
      if ( ! empty( $mod ) ) {
         $return = sprintf('%s { %s:%s; }',
            $selector,
            $style,
            $prefix.$mod.$postfix
         );
         if ( $echo ) {
            echo $return;
         }
      }
      return $return;
    }
}

// Setup the Theme Customizer settings and controls...
add_action( 'customize_register' , array( 'UnReady_Customize' , 'register' ) );

// Enqueue live preview javascript in Theme Customizer admin screen
add_action( 'customize_preview_init' , array( 'UnReady_Customize' , 'live_preview' ) );

// Output custom CSS to live site
add_action( 'wp_head' , array( 'UnReady_Customize' , 'header_output' ) );
```

Thanks Peeps :)

Comment: Please add your code to the question. A question should never rely on an external page.

Comment: Please reduce it to what doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem though.

Comment: I wanted to paste it externally. Not good. you asked me to put in in here. I did. Not good. ??

Comment: I need people to see the whole file to be able to find out what's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My answer might come a bit late for you, but as I had the same problem today, here's what I found out:

1) First of all, if you set `'type' => 'option'` for your custom settings, you should use the `get_option()` function to retrieve the values. If you set `'type' => 'theme_mod'` (or don't set a type at all as it defaults to theme_mod), you can retrieve the values using `get_theme_mod()`

2) Then, if you set your options in an array like `my_theme_option[my_option_value]`, you have to do the following to output the value:

```
$options = get_option('my_theme_option');
echo $options['my_option_value'];
```

Thus, for your CSS output, do this:

```
   public static function header_output() {
      $options = get_option($mytheme_options);
      ?>
      <!--Customizer CSS-->
      <style type="text/css">
          body { color:<?php echo $options['body_background']; ?>; }
          .site-title { color:<?php echo $options['site_title']; ?>; }
          .site-description { color:<?php echo $options['site_description']; ?>; }
          #content a { color:<?php echo $options['link_textcolor']; ?>; }
          #content a:hover { color:<?php echo $options['link_hover_textcolor']; ?>; }
      </style>
      <!--/Customizer CSS-->
      <?php
   }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your function -> get_theme_mod(), skip the option array name and just put the mod name because get_theme_mod() already pulls from the current theme.

So another words change this:

`get_theme_mod('mytheme_options[body_background]');`

To this:

`get_theme_mod('body_background');`